# Want to create UI LABEL dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want to create labels dynamically For e.g. if i have an array with 25 characters stored in it ,i want to create 25 labels for those characters dynamically .I am confused in managing X and Y coordinates .how to manage X and Y coordinates for that.
Can anyone help me .
Any help appreciated .

http://www.chicagonow.com/improv-class-for-the-soul/files/2012/01/Puzzled-1-Quandaries_Enigmas.jpg

Comment: How do you want them positioned? Do you need to access them once you have placed them?

Comment: i want to position them as characters are displayed in  jumbled words puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

```
        int x;
    int y,h,w;
    x=15,y=0,h=135,w=135;
    //int i = array.count;
    int i = CategoryArray.count;
    for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
        if (j==0) {
            x=15;
            y=25;
        }
        else{   
            if (j%2==0) {
                x=15;
                y=y+20+135;
                mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(242, 416+y-80);
            }
            else{
                x=x+135+20;
            }
        }


        
        UILabel *lblFirst = [[UILabel alloc]init] ;
        lblFirst.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, h, w);
        //lblFirst.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        lblFirst.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
        lblFirst.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblFirst.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [lblFirst setText:[[CategoryArray objectAtIndex:j]valueForKey:@"i_name"]];
        [btnImage addSubview:lblFirst];


    }
}
```

Use this code it will help you. in for loop you make Multiple Lable

Comment: You set the all Label in scroll view so u can Manage the screen

Comment: [scrollview addSubview:lbl];

Comment: thanks for answering but by this way i am getting labels in a single line i want to display them as in jumbled words puzzle.

Comment: i have a posted a link of image can you please see that and answer

Comment: Go for Virja's code... he has done a good thing very fast, logic is very simple make a nested loop and once your 11th column is drawn change your x and y, make w & h constant.

Comment: you are welcome if this code is useful then to do right bcoze other are use this code

Comment: You just set the if(j%4==0) insted of j%2 if you want 8 than write j%8